# Compare two column or more column in CSV and merge match data in new csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV files and both have 2 common column (computer name and date).
One CSV file has 5 columns and second CSV has 22 columns.

I want to compare two column data (computer name & date) with second CSV file and if it match then add one more column in CSV 1 (5 column) and insert data from different column.

1st csv data

```
Computer Name   Creation time

12301825        9/1/2013 1:23

23304825        8/1/2013 1:23

43307825        6/1/2013 1:23

53308825        9/1/2013 1:23

63305825        5/1/2013 1:45

73305825        9/1/2013 1:45
```

2nd csv data

```
Computer Name   Creation time   Value

12301825        9/1/2013 1:23   2

27704825        8/1/2013 1:23   3

43307825        6/1/2013 1:23   4

53308825        9/1/2013 1:23   5

63305825        5/1/2013 1:45   9

73305825        9/1/2013 1:45   7
```

I want to compare both column in both csv file and if value match then merge value column in first csv file.

I tried to start creating script but i don't know how it can be done in powershell.

```
$alert=Import-Csv -Path ".\alert.csv" -Header "Computer Name" | Sort-object Property "Computer Name" -Unique 
$threat = Import-Csv ".\threat.csv" -Header "Computer Name" |Sort-Object -Property "Computer Name" -Unique
Compare-Object $alert $threat -Property  "Computer Name" |  Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} | 
    Select-Object  "Computer Name" | export-csv .\Difference.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

It is not a script which I want to create because it is not relevant with my requirement.

### Update

alert.csv contain 22 column and threats.csv contain 5 column. I want to compare threats.csv with alert.csv.

When I run below script I am getting output file like this.

```
$alert=Import-Csv -Path "d:\ps\alert.csv"
$threat = Import-Csv -Path "d:\ps\threat.csv"
ForEach($Record in $threat){
    $MatchedValue = (Compare-Object $alert $Record -Property "Computer Name","Creation time" -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru).value
    $Record = Add-Member -InputObject $Record -Type NoteProperty -Name "Values" -Value $MathedValue
}
$threat|Export-Csv "d:\ps\threatss.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Output in file data

```
PK!?z?b??[Content_Types].xml ??(??T?N?0?#???(q?!?G?|??7?U?????=??V?J???$?????{2?4.[CB|)??Hd?u0?/J?????Iy?\?P?-??M//&o????R?D?NJ?54  Values
"???*?F???J/???ht#u??rj1?t???5??U?g?0??8I??s\0???????*Fg?""V.???a?CUY
&?U?\Ev??   ???d*?  ???W?;????Q??az?8<n?o3?????F`?n???!"    
????[=? 
&$???W?4?K??H"?xR??d?????N?9????Aw(7ey/???O??   
???h?????m?|    
?}D?g"$?4??F?Y??.2#???5?9????Y]b??d??@??%?s?"??0?tB??)???[??????????PK!?p??Hxl/workbook.xml?Q?N?0?#????I????TB??!Q??7?U?l????U
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be over complicating things. Try this:

```
$alert=Import-Csv -Path ".\alert.csv"
$threat = Import-Csv ".\threat.csv"
ForEach($Record in $alert){
    $MatchedValue = (Compare-Object $threat $Record -Property "Computer Name","Creation time" -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru).value
    $Record = Add-Member -InputObject $Record -Type NoteProperty -Name "Value" -Value $MatchedValue
}
$alert|Export-Csv ".\Combined.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Stepping through that, it first imports alert.csv to the $alert dataset. Then does the same for threat.csv and $threat. It then steps through each record in the $alert dataset, and looks for matching records in $threat where Computer Name and Creation Time are equal. It saves the Value field from the matching record in $threat, adds that value (if any) to the current record in $alert, and moves on to the next record in $alert. After parsing through all records in $alert it exports the combined dataset to Combined.csv.

Let me know if you have any issues or questions.