# Compare 2 csv to create list of unique items in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 csv files and need to create a 3rd.

**csv_1** (only 1 column)

```
USERNAME
guy1
guy2
guy3
```

**csv_2**

```
"ID","USERNAME","GROUPU"
"1","guyA","Default"
"2","guy1","Default"
"3","guyB","Default"
"4","guy3","Default"
"5","guyC","Default"
```

for an output from comparing these two tables I'd like to see:

```
USERNAME,ID
guy1,2
guy3,4
```

I tried this and it dumped far too much data (listing all entries multiple times)

```
$file1 = Import-Csv csv_1.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv csv_2.csv

foreach ($line in $file1){
    $U1 = $line.User
    foreach ($line in $file2)
        $U2 = $line.USERNAME
        $I2 = $line.ID
        If ($U1 = $U2){
            $x = $U2+","+$I2
            ac temp.csv$x
            }
        }
    }
```

I added a break:outside line after the ac temp.csv $x line but then it only listed 1 entry multiple times.

I also tries this (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433993/compare-two-column-or-more-column-in-csv-and-merge-match-data-in-new-csv) entry):

```
$file1 = Import-Csv csv_1.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv csv_2.csv

ForEach($Record in $file1){
    $MatchedValue = (Compare-Object $file2 $Record -Property "USERNAME" -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru).value
    $Record = Add-Member -InputObject $Record -Type NoteProperty -Name "SQLID" -Value $MatchedValue
    }
$file1 #|Export-Csv ".\Combined.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

but didn't get anything in the SQLID column and it included some values in $file1 that are not in $file2.  I figure the lack of SQLID value is because I need to add a variable there (the -value just being $matchedValue which is just the line from $file1), but I'm not sure how to get the variable from the correct record in $file2.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each entry in `$file1`, test if an entry in `$file2` has the same USERNAME property value. If so, select the USERNAME and ID Properties and add the entry to a collection that you can write back to the final csv file:

```
$file1 = Import-Csv .\csv_1.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv .\csv_2.csv

$users = @()

foreach($u in $file1)
{
    $u2 = $file2 |Where-Object {$_.USERNAME -eq $u.USERNAME}|Select USERNAME,ID -First 1 
    if($u2)
    { $users += $u2 }
}

$users|Export-Csv -Path .\csv_3.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Thank you - this got me moving in the right direction.  This worked right until I encountered an entry in csv_1 that is NOT in csv_2.  the csv_3 file gets built up to the point where $u2 is a null entry.  I changed `$users += $u2` to `if ($u2){$users += $u2}` and it worked like a champ.