# Using PowerShell to compare and modify CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to create a script that can compare 2 CSV files, find the similarities in them and then delete said lines.

Now I can't give anyone access to the files because they hold private information but I've added some sample files [the sample files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bEq0AXOXyw3pUOFoHcwBU1-YS4kVfloe) so you have an idea of what I'm working with, in my test data sample1 is meant to be an all staff list and sample2 is staff at a certain location eg: all staff employed at a school vs all staff that belong to a campus

if you can see my sample data you will notice that there is one name that doesn't appear in both documents my goal is to only have the non repeating data exporting into a new CSV file. one of the biggest problems that I can see if that in the data I'm using the password field is different in both documents and cannot be changed so I won't able to do a `Compare-Object`.

Comment: Duplicate:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339300/compare-two-csv-and-export-only-a-list-of-names-that-dont-exist-in-both
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616022/compare-two-csv-using-powershell-and-return-matching-and-non-matching-values
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220782/compare-2-csv-files-and-write-all-differences
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448684/compare-2-csv-to-create-list-of-unique-items-in-powershell

Comment: thanks for the links @RaghavDinesh